# Yarn 2 logfilters for Default Steps

Tags: logging, filter, yarn-v2, yarnpkg-v2, yarnrc

In Yarn 2 I am using `logFilters` to hide some logs. This works for warnings, but I would like to hide the default messages, such as `Resolution step` etc as well. Except for `Done`.

[image]

How can I achieve that? Please find my `.yarnrc.yml` code below:

```
logFilters:
  - code: "YN0002"
    level: discard
  - code: "YN0060"
    level: discard
  - text: "Resolution step"
    level: discard
  - text: "Fetch step"
    level: discard
  - text: "Link step"
    level: discard
  - pattern: "*Completed in *"
    level: discard
```

Comment: Are you using a version above 2.4 of Yarn?

Comment: @MohamedChaawa I'm not sure. I am using Yarn 2, but when I run `yarn -v` it says `1.22.19`. I updated last week. And in my `package.json` I use `"packageManager": "yarn@3.2.4"`